# Batch Code to Replace a Multiline Text File with > /< symbols Included

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename, multiple-choice

I need to create a batch file you can run that will edit a txt file, with 5 separate choices of what to how to edit.  The file is a config file for a program that targets it at specific a specific server.  Rather than change the specific server I thought it would be easier to just rewrite the whole thing (its only 8 lines).  My current issue is that the file contains multiple uses of < and >.

Example of the file being created:

```
<AppSettings>
  <IsWebService>False</IsWebService>
  <AppServerIP>IP address</AppServerIP>
  <AppServerPort>Port Number</AppServerPort>
  <EnterpriseID />
  <CentralFileServerIP>IP address</CentralFileServerIP>
  <CentralFileServerPort>Port number</CentralFileServerPort>
</AppSettings>
```

Currently I am getting syntax errors after the first  (I am just working on option 1 currently).

Full bat file currently:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO Which agency would you like to switch to?
ECHO 1.COMME70 - Commercial Underwriters Ins Agency, LLC
ECHO 2.CLEME12 - Clements Insurance Services
ECHO 3.MCELV02 - McElveen Insurance and Bonds
ECHO 4.JONES46 - Jones Insurance Services, LLC
ECHO 5.RIGIN01 - Rig Insurance Services, LLC
ECHO.

CHOICE /C 12345 /M "Enter your choice:"

IF ERRORLEVEL 5 GOTO RIGIN01
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO JONES46
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO MCELV02
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO CLEME12
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO COMME70

:COMME70
ECHO Loading  COMME70 Data
del C:\ASI\ASI.TAM\ThinClient\Data\SMART.config
ECHO Previous data deleted
ECHO Setting up new data

echo ^<AppSettings^>^ 

> C:\ASI\ASI.TAM\ThinClient\Data\SMART.config

GOTO End

**********Other options added here*************

GOTO End

:End
```

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, given that you haven't specified where the error message is occurring, so we have to read and assess all of code, which wastes our time.

```
echo ^<AppSettings^>^ 

> C:\ASI\ASI.TAM\ThinClient\Data\SMART.config
```

The final caret in the `echo` line effectively appends the second line in this sequence of three lines to the first, hence `cmd` sees

```
echo ^<AppSettings^>
> C:\ASI\ASI.TAM\ThinClient\Data\SMART.config
```

Which is clearly an `echo` command (you failed to mention any output) followed by a redirected *nothing* command, which would provide a syntax error.

HOWEVER...the `echo` line has a terminal <kbd>space</kbd> so the caret redundantly escapes the <kbd>Space</kbd>, not the <kbd>new line</kbd>

and `cmd` interprets

```
echo ^<AppSettings^>  

> C:\ASI\ASI.TAM\ThinClient\Data\SMART.config
```

...Same problem, but the `echo` has a terminal <kbd>Space</kbd> and there is an empty line before the redirected *nothing* command

```
(
echo ^<AppSettings^>
)> C:\ASI\ASI.TAM\ThinClient\Data\SMART.config
```

will probably do what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't repeat the code to write the file, so it's simpler to maintain in the future. Use variables instead. This way you have a single template which is just filled with different data:

```
@echo off
rem ...
if %errorlevel% == 1 set "EnterpriseID=Commercial Underwriters Ins Agency, LLC" & set "IPaddress=256.315.412.523"
if %errorlevel% == 2 (
  set "EnterpriseID=Clements Insurance Services"
  set "IPaddress=257.318.413.524"
)
rem ...

>"C:\ASI\ASI.TAM\ThinClient\Data\SMART.config" (
for %%a in (
    "<AppSettings>"
    "  <IsWebService>False</IsWebService>"
    "  <AppServerIP>IP address</AppServerIP>"
    "  <AppServerPort>Port Number</AppServerPort>"
    "  <%EnterpriseID% />"
    "  <CentralFileServerIP>%IPaddress%</CentralFileServerIP>"
    "  <CentralFileServerPort>Port number</CentralFileServerPort>"
    "</AppSettings>"
  ) do @echo %%~a 
)
```

(I had to guess what to insert where; just to show the principle)

Quotes around the string protect poison chars (like `<`, `>`, but also `&`, which is quite common in enterprise names). The tilde in `%%~a` removes them later. This is much easier and better to read than escaping poison chars.